# Promise { <pending> } Error while working with Geoserver Rest API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, geoserver

Anyone has any idea about this and how would I be able to get the correct outcome?

I have used the Promise and async/await properties in here

```
layers = async () => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let options = {
        url: `http://geoserverIP/geoserver/rest/workspaces/datastores/featuretypes.json`,
        auth: {
            'user': 'admin',
            'pass': 'geoserver'
        }
    }

    request(options, (err, resp, body) => {
        if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
            return resolve(JSON.parse(body))

        } else if (!err) {
            return reject({
                status: 404,
                errors: [{
                    messages: ["Workspace or datastore not found"]
                }]
            })

        } else {
            return reject({
                status: 500,
                errors: [{
                    messages: ["Failed connection with geoserver"]
                }]
            })
        }
    })
})
}

console.log(layers())
```

I expect to get the list of layers but I get "Promise {pending}"

Comment: Remove those 'return' before 'resolve'  and 'reject' calls.

Answer (score 2):

When you mark a function as `async` by default returns a `Promise` also you are returning `Promise` explicitly.

To use the value either you can `await` the function or can make a `.then` chain.

```
(async ()=>{
    const data = await layers();
    console.log(data);
})();
```

or

```
layers().then((data)=>{
    console.log(data)
});
```

**Note:** As you are not using any `await` keyword inside the function you don't need to mark it as `async`

**EDIT1:** You can use `axios` instead of `request`, it by default returns promise.

Comment: So you mean I should remove async? It gives the same error.

Comment: No, you should remove the async but also to work with the promise you need to use `await` or `.then` just like i did above.

Comment: Sorry there was one syntax error, forgot to add the calling braces. `(async ()=>{
})*()*;`